# How can I connect to a VPN in docker not using VPN images?

Tags: docker, containers, vpn

Good morning!

Im using check point mobile to connect to my client VPN, and I have 2 containers in docker: mysql and karaf both sharing the network I created using the command `docker network create --subnet=vpnAddress mynet`

I used the command `--network=mynet` when running the containers.

Until here its all ok, I can connect via putty ssh to karaf, install the kar and all bundles are ok.

But when calling the services I realize that the container is not connected to the VPN, even so that I created a network with the VPN address. I need to be connected to the VPN in order to call the services.

Im connected externally(outside docker) to the VPN using the check point mobile, but I need docker to add/connect to the VPN.

Im using windows 10 (using docker with linux containers), I tried to go to `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\tmp-d4w` and edit the file `host.docker.internal` too and change the IP to my VPN address, but none works.

I searched a lot, and I saw people talking about docker vpn images such as nordVpn or openVpn, but I cant use that.

I have been told I need to add the vpn network to docker, But im green at networking and I dont know how to do it, and what I did didn't work.

Hope you can help me. thanks!

edit: in docker engine i added the `"bip": "vpnAddress/24"`
I realize now that network bridge uses the VPN address now, tried to `--network=bridge` in both karaf and mysql container, but now karaf cant connect to mysql, but if I use the default `docker create network mynet` and run the 2 container using that network it works, but no luck with the VPN this way.

Comment: You should declare VPN port when you running a container with -p flag.

Comment: @anlgrses I just tried that. did a netstat -a and saw the ipv4 address from the vpn connection, I added 2 ports to karaf container, the one that says "Listening" and the one who says "established". even so, no luck :(

Comment: Using a VPN container really isn't a option? It's very easy and secure to use one VPN container and share network with the container you need (otherwise you'd need to set NET_ADMIN capabilities to your container). You're probably connected in the VPN on your Windows, but Docker is probably running in a VM over Hyper-V, so it's not inheriting the default gateway from your Windows setup

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto I would like to, but I dont have the certificate, and was told I could do it without it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't used Docker on Windows, but a quick look at some VPN containers shows that, in *nix at least, they use `--device /dev/net/tun --cap-add=NET_ADMIN` to expose the VPN "device" to the container. Other containers then use docker networking or links to connect to this VPN container - so looking at how the VPN containers do it might be helpful.

One suggestion for Mac seems to be [using extra_hosts](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2820) like so:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "vpn.company.com:172.21.1.1"
```

You might be able to hack it with something like that. (or physically adding `172.21.1.1 vpn.company.com` to `/etc/hosts` in the container). Also, checking for [IP address conflicts](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1803) between the Docker daemon and your host machine.

[Windows docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/architecture) seem to suggest they don't support network interfaces as "devices", so you probably need to either create a very specific docker network or modify host networking settings, starting with getting Docker daemon to recognize the VPN network.

See the [Configure Advanced Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/advanced) section for some examples. I'd try creating a network associated with the VPN device first, then look into flags like `--subnet` and  `--gateway`.

```
docker network create -d transparent \
    -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.interface="Ethernet 2" TransparentNet2
```

This creates a network with a particular subnet and gateway, then runs a container with a statically-assigned IP on that network.

```
C:\> docker network create -d transparent \
    --subnet=10.123.174.0/23 \
    --gateway=10.123.174.1 MyTransparentNet

C:\> docker run -it --network=MyTransparentNet \
    --ip=10.123.174.105 windowsservercore cmd
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really apreciate it! Im going to try what you told me right now.

Comment: I tried both options you game me.
1- adding the ip in etc/hosts inside de container. It didn't work.
2- creating a network, but It game the message: "Error response from daemon: plugin "transparent" not found."
I did some search, all I found was that transparent is used only in windows containers, but not sure about that info.

Or maybe I explained myself bad and you thought I was using windows containers, if so, sorry about that.
Im using docker on windows 10, but im using docker linux containers.

Is there any way around? or a similar command? thanks!

Comment: I was finally able to do it :)

It was basically as you said, I created a network associated with the VPN and used the --network command to give the container that network to use.

I did a ping in container to the VPN and it was OK. the problem I was having too, is that using VPN I needed to pass another IP so I could call the services. adding in etc/hosts didnt do it because when restarting karaf the ip is removed from there.
So after searching more I realised I had to add: --add-host=example:ip when running the container.
Worked as expected after that!
thanks!